# ¿De donde viene la expresión "equilicuá"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, españa

Esta mañana usé la palabra **"equilicuá"** y quise saber más sobre ella y si mi uso fue correcto.

Buscando su significado veo: (<strike>No sale en la RAE ni en el panhispánico.</strike>)

> *interjección*
>
> Se utiliza como expresión exclamativa, señalando hacia un lugar o haciendo referencia a la solución que se ha encontrado a un asunto, para indicar que ahí está lo que se buscaba y que por fin se ha dado con ello.

Como uso que se le pueda dar, por ejemplo:

> Amigo: ¿Dónde he dejado las llaves? No las encuentro.
> Yo: ¿Has mirado debajo de esa bolsa?
> Amigo: ¡Equilicuá! Ahí estaban.

La pregunta que me viene es: ¿qué origen tiene esta expresión?

Comment: ¿Pero de dónde sacáis que no está en el DRAE? http://dle.rae.es/?id=FznyqUR

Comment: @blonfu como pude no verlo :O

Comment: @blonfu lo peor es no solo lois6b buscó sino que yo también busqué en el DRAE y tampoco la encontré.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Viene del italiano *[eccoli](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=ecco) qua*, Qué significa literalmente "helos acá" o "acá están". Respecto de *ecco* en italiano, dice el enlace:

> si unisce ai pronomi personali atoni *mi*, *ti*, *ci*, *vi*, *lo*, *la*, *le*, *li* e alla particella *ne*: *eccomi!*; ***eccolo!***; *eccone alcuni* | può essere seguito dagli avverbi di luogo *qui*, ***qua***, *lì*, *là*, *laggiù*: *ecco laggiù Massimo*.

O, en español:

> se usa unido a los pronombres personales átonos *mi*, *ti*, *ci*, *vi*, *lo*, *la*, *le*, *li* y a la partícula *ne*: *eccomi!*; ***eccolo!***; *eccone alcuni* | puede usarse seguido de los adverbios de lugar *qui*, ***qua***, *lì*, *là*, *laggiù*: *ecco laggiù Massimo*.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta! a mi el *qua* me sonaba francés hahah

Answer (score 5):

Argentina / Uruguay: Es "¡ecolecuá!" que proviene del italiano "eccoli qua"
a veces se utiliza alternativamente "ecole!".
usualmente es una exclamación que se utiliza al descubrir, encontrar o confirmar una cosa o situación.
Ej: cuando uno estaba a la espera de que ocurra algo y ocurre. o buscando, se usa de manera similar también al "¡acá esta!" o "¡acá vienen!" "¡acá llegan!" se da sobretodo en personas con ascendencia italiana, pero se difundió mucho mas ampliamente, hoy en día, se encuentra menos frecuentemente dado a que las mas recientes olas migratorias (ultimas 3 o 4 décadas) a estos lugares pertenecen a países limítrofes o de la región (con unas menores de paises asiaticos y aun pequeñas de países africanos) donde esta expresión es inexistente a diferencia de las que originaron este termino que fueron provenientes de Italia.

Como dato extra, a veces se utiliza "¡ecole!" al ser este mas corto.

Answer (score 0):

Es muy usada la palabra entre cubanos y se la debemos a los inmigrantes italianos